# String out of bound

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Decision
{

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            String name[] = new String[75];
            double basic[] = new double[75];
            char grade[] = new char[75];
            double net[] = new double[75];
            int i;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            for(i=0;i<75;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the name , basic salary and grade(A/B/C)of the employee");
                name[i]=sc.nextLine();
                basic[i]=sc.nextDouble();
                grade[i]=sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
                if(grade[i]!='A'||grade[i]!='a'||grade[i]!='B'||grade[i]!='b'||grade[i]!='C'||grade[i]!='c')
                    {
                        System.out.println("Grade must be A/B/C, Please re-enter again");
                        i--;
                    }
            }
        double da,hra,ma,it,bs;
        char c;
            System.out.println("Name\tBasic\tDA\tHRA\tMA\tIT\tNetSalary");
            for(i=0;i<75;i++)
            {
                c=grade[i];
```

I am getting error grade[i]=sc.nextLine() , even i tried grade[i]=sc.nextLine().charAt(0) but it is showing out of bound

Comment: @nullpointer next iteration `i` is increased by one, which makes it 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

```
sc.nextDouble()
```

doesn't consume the newline after the double. This means that when you call `sc.nextLine()` afterwards, you get everything between the end of the double and the new line - which is an empty string - and so `sc.nextLine().charAt(0)` yields a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Add a `nextLine()` call afterwards:

```
        basic[i]=sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();  // This
        grade[i]=sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Alternatively, read the double as a string, and parse it yourself:

```
        basic[i]=Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
        grade[i]=sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
```